# Did any Western country ban Japanese seafood as a result of the release of nuclear wastewater?

Tags: international, japan, nuclear-energy

> Russia on Monday followed its ally China in suspending all Japanese
> seafood imports over Tokyo's release of wastewater from the crippled
> Fukushima nuclear plant.
>
> Japan has been sharply critical of Russia's invasion of Ukraine, while
> Tokyo's relations with Beijing — which has deepened ties with Moscow —
> have worsened.
>
> Rosselkhoznadzor, Russia's body responsible for regulating agriculture
> products, said it was "joining China's provisional restrictive
> measures on the import of fish and seafood products from Japan as of
> October 16, 2023" as a "precautionary measure."
>
> It said the restrictions would remain in place "until the necessary
> exhaustive information to confirm the safety of seafood produce ... is
> forthcoming."

https://www.voanews.com/a/after-china-russia-suspends-japanese-seafood-imports-/7312507.html

Did any Western country ban Japanese seafood as a result of the release of nuclear wastewater? Russia and China did ban Japanese seafood for that specific reason, but I was wondering if other countries followed suit in the West, because it seems like a political decision that motivated Russia to do the same against Japan.

Comment: It's worth noting that the water from Fukushima only has small amounts of Tritium in it. [The IAEA monitors the releases closely](https://www.iaea.org/topics/response/fukushima-daiichi-nuclear-accident/fukushima-daiichi-alps-treated-water-discharge/faq)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there were no import bans in the "West" (still not sure what that means) At least neither the EU not US have import restrictions.

However Japan doesn't export much fish to "the West". It is significant importer, not exporter of seafood.

Comment: To my knowledge there used to be significant seafood trade from Japan to China, so that restriction did have an impact. I don't think there is any non-trivial seafood trade from Japan to Russia, so this measure doesn't have any noticeable consequences.

Comment: Yes, Seafood is highly perishable, and China has a very large market, so there was exports to China.  But Japan is a net importer of seafood.

Comment: Just market it as "Pasteurized" fish.